# How to test that a sequence of variances rank ascendingly?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, inequality

I am investigating forecast optimality. [Diebold (2017, p. 334, list item **d**)](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) indicates that one of the desirable properties of a good forecast is

> Optimal forecasts have $h$-step-ahead errors with variances that are nondecreasing in $h$ <...>.

I would like to test this for my forecasts. I have $H$ series of forecasts:

- a series of 1-step-ahead forecasts,
- a series of 2-step-ahead forecasts,
- ...
- a series of $H$-step-ahead forecasts

with their corresponding series of forecast errors:

- a series of 1-step-ahead forecast errors (a vector $e_1$) with theoretical variance $\sigma_1^2$ and estimated variance $\hat\sigma_1^2$,
- a series of 2-step-ahead forecast errors (a vector $e_2$) with theoretical variance $\sigma_2^2$ and estimated variance $\hat\sigma_2^2$,
- ...
- a series of $H$-step-ahead forecast errors (a vector $e_H$) with theoretical variance $\sigma_H^2$ and estimated variance $\hat\sigma_H^2$.

Each forecast error series corresponds to the same target series. Therefore, the shocks that occur during the lifetime of a forecast$^1$  overlap across series$^2$, making all $H$ forecast error series dependent.

**Question**: How may I test whether the variances of the forecast errors are nondecreasing w.r.t. the forecast horizon, i.e. $\sigma_1^2 \leq \dots \leq \sigma_H^2$?

**References**

- Diebold ["Forecasting in Economics, Business, Finance and Beyond"](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) (version of 1st August 2017)

---

$^1$ The lifetime is 1 time period for 1-step-ahead forecast, ..., $H$ time periods for $H$-step-ahead forecast.
$^2$ For a given target, there is 1 shock that is common to all $H$ horizons, ..., $H-1$ shocks that are common to the longest two horizons.

---

Related older question: ["Comparing variances of forecast errors"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193090).

Comment: I expect testing this kind of hypothesis is incredibly complicated for $H\geq 3$... A somewhat related question ["How to test whether $\mu_1<\mu_2<\mu_3$?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402604).

Comment: In a strongly seasonal series it might well be that exactly one-season-ahead forecast are more precise than, say, 10-months-ahead forecasts ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, sure, that is a good point.

Comment: You could look into the `restriktor` package on CRAN